# NSLayoutConstraint best fitting size automatically?

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I've a view created in code that i use in one of my controllers, all created in code, all constraints created programatically. Now, my constraints work perfectly, except my view doesn't seem to want to adopt a compressed height (and I have no idea how to make it). If I dont constrain its height in my controller, it just ends up being longer than it needs to be. I know I have to add constraints with subviews, but that's also problematic because I have two case scenarios: the image is the lowest subview or the uilabel is the lowest subview shown in the image:

[image]

How can I create a constraint that will make sure the views is compressed vertically?

Comment: By compressed height do you mean you want it to auto fit to the content?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the vertical hugging of the enclosing view to some high value or required (`1000`). If the view you want to hug its content is some custom view you created, you'll need to override the view's `intrinsicContentSize` to return a correct value (at least for the height; you can return `UIViewNoInstrinsicMetric` for the width if you need to).

Comment: Will my views be layed out at the point where intrinsicContentSize is used?

Comment: This doesn't help. My subview's frames are CGRectZero by the time I'm calculating intrinsicContentSize(). How am I supposed to return the correct value if I have no idea where my views are?

Comment: You should brush up on your auto-layout documentation. The auto-layout system asks the views involved in layout for their intrinsic content size automatically. It's not up to you to "know where your views are"; rather, you're only providing the *content size* of a custom view (and only if it's a custom view whose content you provide yourself!). It's also none of your business what a view's frames are when using auto-layout. Remember also you *must* call `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()` when your view's content changes. Again, it's time to re-read the docs.

Comment: Addendum: Please edit and update your question to include the latest changes where you tried to implement my suggestions. You might be Doing It Wrong™. Also, to clarify: 1) Remember I said `intrinsicContentSize` matters only if you're using a custom view, and 2) "frame" has nothing to do with it if you're providing custom content (ie, you should already know what size you need to display its custom content; frame is just that size and an origin (a rectangle) anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 constraints

1) superview.bottom >= image.bottom + bottom margin (constant)

2) superview.bottom >= lastitem.bottom + bottom margin (constant)